# Python3 Incorrect AES key length (256 bytes)

Tags: python, encryption, aes, pycryptodome

I want to write a script that encrypts the content of a text file (key.k3y). When i execute it, i get the error: Incorrect AES key length (256 Bytes). Obviously that should not be invalid for AES. here is my code:

```
import base64
import pycryptodome
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Util.Padding import pad
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.kdf.pbkdf2 import PBKDF2HMAC

# Set a password and encode it (to Byte type)
password_provided = "NHW!He2-vxxYWF7va23LzjnqFTyvP#dAPGHChXmmSY4YYzJ*HDX_HzRZ-7M8c*2t" #64chars
password = password_provided.encode()
print(len(password))
# Set the hashing parameters for the pw hashing
salt = b'\x08\xfc\xe4e\x89\xc2\xa8\xfe\xe2UsS\xbb#\xbe\x8d\xec\x9b\xb1\xf9\x9d]\xa6D?\xc7\x89\x1b\xdf\xb7\xa3\x19m\x13\xca"i\xbbd\x07b\x8al\x80@xm>Coa\xcc\x88X\xc7@\x99\xd5\xf8\xcf\x86\x04\xbf9'

kdf = PBKDF2HMAC(
    algorithm=hashes.SHA512(),
    length=192,
    salt=salt,
    iterations=100000,
    backend=default_backend()
)

# Hash and encode the key with SHA512 and base64
key = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(kdf.derive(password))
print("The key (hashed pw) is: ")
print(len(key))

# Get the message or, as in this case, the content of the file key.k3y
messagefile = open('key.k3y', 'rb')
data = messagefile.read()
messagefile.close()

# Encrypting the message with AES, mode CBC
cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC)
encdata = cipher.encrypt(pad(data, AES.block_size))
print(encdata)
```

Comment: `key = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(kdf.derive(password))` should be `key = kdf.derive(password)`. If you want to transmit the key through a textual media or print it only then should you encode it. **Also**, `length=192,` should be `length=32,` if you want an 256 bit key

Comment: An AES key may be 128, 192, or 256 **bits**. A key of length 256 **bytes** is indeed invalid